# Order of installation? SQL Server 2008 + SP2 + New instance of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-pack

I installed a SQL Server 2008 Express instance. Then I installed SQL Server 2008 SP1. Now I want to install a second, seperate instance of 2008 Express.

After I install, do I need to **re-run** the executable for SP1? Or does it apply to all future installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-run SP1